# Вопросы про регистры и какие значения надо в них вставлять

Tags: ассемблер, nasm

В общем есть такой код:

```
section .data
    msg db 'Hello,world!',0xa
    len equ $ - msg
    
section .text
    global _start
    
_start:
    mov edx,len
    mov ecx,msg
    mov ebx,1
    mov eax,4
    
    int 0x80
    
    mov eax,1
    int 0x80
```

И есть вот такие типы регистров:

```
EAX (Accumulator): для арифметических операций

ECX (Counter): для хранения счетчика цикла

EDX (Data): для арифметических операций и операций ввода-вывода

EBX (Base): указатель на данные

ESP (Stack pointer): указатель на верхушку стека

EBP (Base pointer): указатель на базу стека внутри функции

ESI (Source index): указатель на источник при операциях с массивом

EDI (Destination index): указатель на место назначения в операциях с массивами

EIP: указатель адреса следующей инструкции для выполнения

EFLAGS: регистр флагов, содержит биты состояния процессора
```

**Есть несколько вопросов:**

1. Почему большинство регистров используются не по назначению? Например,зачем мы вставляем (грубо говоря) переменную в регистр ECX? Ведь он является счётчиком цикла.
2. Чтобы вывести на экран текст, мы должны вставить в EAX - 4, а в EBX - 1. Вопрос: зачем? Это типо системные вызовы (команды)? Какие есть ещё? Есть ли таблица этих команд?

*Простите, если вопрос кажется глупым*

Comment: Первые восемь перечисленных регистров являются регистрами общего назначения и их в принципе можно использовать для чего угодно.

Comment: Указанное назначение регистров сейчас достаточно условное. Раньше было строже, например, при 16-битной регистрации базовыми регистрами можно указывать только BP и BX, в качестве индексных - SI, DI, сейчас соответствующие регистры можно почти в любой роли использовать.

Comment: "Это типо системные вызовы (команды)?" - системные вызовы. Можно тут, например, почитать (если нужно, используйте google translate, например): https://www.baeldung.com/linux/system-calls-vs-library-calls

Comment: @user7860670, а как понять какой нужно использовать для файлового дескриптора, куда вставлять длину строки, саму строку?

Comment: @ХодячийСишник читать документацию по соответствующим системным вызовам.